# Weirdness when saving a new file with Sublime Text 2, it creates an extra file

Tags: sublimetext2

Every time I save new file created within Sublime Text 2 I get an extra file with hex numbers in it.

Example:

> C + N (new file)
>
> C + S (save file)
>
> I save it as: "test.rb"
>
> Now I have: "test.rb" and "._test.rb"

Why? What is the extra file full of hex numbers? How can I prevent this?

Comment: What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Package Control - RubyMotion Autocomplete - Trailing Spaces

Comment: Hmm well, unsure what the exact problem is, but I'd guess it was a plugin, as ST itself shouldn't be doing anything special. Perhaps you installed and have subsequently removed a plugin before? You could also try checking your settings. Perhaps you installed another plugin not through package control. Most provide some access to settings through the menus.